# Apache Ignite 3 Support for C++ thin client

Tags: c++, ignite, thin-client

Is there any roadmap in apache ignite 3 to include the thin client for c++ ? This is with respect to the backward compatability support for apache ignite 2.6 which support c++ thin client.

I have looked at the apache ignite 3 documentation and I couldnt find any reference to c++ thin client.

Comment: Ask this question towards the apache ignite community using whatever communication channels they have available.

Comment: @Botje this site is considered one of our communication channels, many community members are subscribed to the ignite tag.

Comment: Here's the documentation for the C++ client: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-beta/thin-clients/index#c-client-2

Answer (score 2):

Ignite 3 already has C++ client, it is our priority along with Java and .NET clients:

https://github.com/apache/ignite-3/tree/main/modules/platforms/cpp